# use textbox as input for jQuery function

Tags: jquery, html

I am a jQuery newbie and was wondering whether it is possible to pass in a TextBox as an argument for a jQuery function. Something like this:

```
<input id="MyInput" value="" type="text" >

//how/what to pass in this function to change the value of the input?
function SetValueTextBox(? ?)  
{
//change the value of the MyInput Textbox

}
```

Ofcourse i have more than 1 TextBox where I would like to use this hence the question.

Comment: Learn jQuery. We cannot help people who doesn't know this library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this (not 100% sure what you looking for):

```
function SetValueTextBox(textboxid, value)  
    {
    //change the value of the MyInput Textbox
    $('#' + textboxid).val(value);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function ChangeValue(value) {
  $("#MyInput").val(value);
}
```

Please learn jQuery and read it's documentation.

Answer (score 1):

DOM element can be set as a variable as well as a jQuery object.

```
function SetValueTextBox(el, val) {
    el.val(val);
}

var field = $("#MyInput");
SetValueTextBox(field, "new value");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to change the value displayed in the text box, you can just use something like:

```
jQuery("#MyInput").val("something");
```

You could even go jQuery-less, with:

```
document.getElementById("MyInput").value = "something"
```

In this case, you'll probably want to replace `"something"` with one of your arguments.